# Google Map display unnecessary blank space at the end of map. i am using gmaps4rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails

**How to manage pan up and down so it display only map,Not display unnecessary blank space.**

[image]

Comment: I am using google chrome.

Comment: very weird, you sure its not a css issue? whats the generated js?

Comment: i copied code from apneadiving.github.io site and there is also same issue while so many times zoom-out google map.

Comment: @apneadiving - do you have any solution of my problem?

Comment: gmaps4rails doesnt do anthing particular, it just creates a regular google map. I bet you have a css issue